# Force vertical alignment despite lack of text?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertically center a `display:inline-block` element with `vertical-align:middle`. The problem is that it doesn't vertically align in the absolute center until the text reaches that point.

See: http://jsbin.com/afojew/1/edit

This works, but is a bit hacky: http://jsbin.com/afojew/2/edit 
edit: ^ that doesn't quite work, but this does: http://jsbin.com/afojew/3/edit

Comment: Do you know what the height of `.centered` will be?  Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: It's hacky but without those new css box layouts and stuff, centering anything like this vertically will always be hacky. The solution you presented is actually my preferred way of doing it. I set the font-size to 0, though, instead of removing the width. I  also use a pseudo element instead of a real element. You perhaps considered using one too, I don't know. I modified your fiddle here: http://jsbin.com/afojew/20/edit

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before - Ive just read it and it contains pretty much everything you would need to know with this problem : [Vertically align text in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)